# Ayuda con el manejo de datos en Oracle, como emplear el TO_CHAR para un tipo de dato NUMBER?

Tags: java, oracle, sql

Tengo una consulta la cual obtiene datos de tipo NUMBER en la BD, lo que hago es mostrar el resultado de la consulta en un archivo .csv y a la hora de mostrar esos datos los campos de tipo NUMBER  los cuales son `(IMPORTE_UNO, IMPORTE_DOS)` no muestra los decimales, para ello hice uso del `to_char`

Mi consulta es esta

```html
SELECT F.ID, F.NOMBRE, TO_CHAR(F.FECHA_INI,'DD/MM/YYYY'), TO_CHAR(F.FECHA_REGISTRO,'DD/MM/YYYY'), TO_CHAR(F.FECHA.CARGA,'DD/MM/YYYY'), TO_CHAR(F.IMPORTE_UNO,'fm9990.00'), TO_CHAR(F.IMPORTE_DOS,'fm9990.00'), F.ENTIDAD_REC
FROM FACTURA F
WHERE (?1 IS NULL OR  F.ID =?1)
AND F.FECHA_INI &gt;= TO_DATE(?2 'DD/MM/YYYY')
AND F.FECHA_INI &lt;= TO_DATE(?3 'DD/MM/YYYY')
```

Esos campos estan definidos asi en la BD

```html
IMPORTE_UNO  NUMBER(12,2)
IMPORTE_DOS  NUMBER(16,2)
```

Lo que no se y me gustaría que me aclararan, es que si esta bien la manera en la que empleo el `TO_CHAR(F.IMPORTE_DOS,'fm9990.00')` o deben de ir 12 veces el "9" a la izquierda por que asi esta definido ese campo `IMPORTE_UNO  NUMBER(12,2)`, no se mucho acerca de Oracle y no se si es correcto, que significa NUMBER(12,2)??

En mi código java esos campos están mapeados como Double

Comment: NUMBER(12,2) es un numero de longitud 12 con 2 decimales.

Comment: NUMBER(12,2) significa el tipo de dato, en este caso NUMBER(t, d), donde t es la precisión y significa el número total de dígitos, en tu caso 12, y d es la escala y significa el número máximo de decimales, en tu caso 2. por tanto, ese campo admite valores desde -9999999999.99 a 9999999999.99, que son 10 dígitos en la parte entera y 2 en la decimal. Si tienes problemas también con Excel y los decimales, que no te los interpreta correctamente, guárdalos como texto en el csv añadiendo las comillas comillas ("campo")

Answer (score 1):

La manera que declaras `TO_CHAR(F.IMPORTE_DOS,'fm9990.00')` es correcta si esta cumple con tu objetivo. Me explico, `fm9990.00` **significa que no quieres espacios en blancos sobrantes al añadir "fm"** y tu número más grande es el 9999.99 y el mas pequeño es el 0.00.

**Al añadir 0.00 indicas quieres de manera obligatoria 1 entero y 2 decimales:**

FORMATO : ENTRADA > SALIDA

- 0.0 : 0 > 0.0
- 0.0 : 2 > 2.0
- 0.00 : 0 > 2.00
- 000.00 : 5.5 > 005.50

**Al añadir los 9 indicas número opcionales:**

- 90.00 : 10 > 10.00
- 90.00 : 1 > 1.00
- 90.00 : 200 > #####

--EDITED---
Un ejemplo real de BBDD donde INVERSION es del tipo **`NUMBER(5,2)` significa que el "5" es el número total de dígitos donde del total(5) va a tener 2 decimales** es decir tu número más grande será el 999.99 y el menor -999,99 (precisión,escala).

```
SELECT INVERSION FROM EXPE ->
   3000,59
         0
        26
      35,5
```

Esto es lo que devuelve de manera normal Oracle. Ahora fijate lo que pasa cuando añades el to_char():

```
SELECT to_char(INVERSION, 'fm9990.00') FROM EXPE ->
3000.59
0.00
26.00
35.50
```

Fijate como el resultado está formateado a la izquierda y ha cambiado la "," por un ".", esto te puede resultar útil ya que al final vas a trabajar con EXEL y para no tener que configurar nada.

Si quitamos el "fm" nos devuelve lo siguiente:

```
SELECT to_char(INVERSION, '9990.00') FROM EXPE ->
3000.59
   0.00
  26.00
  35.50
```

Espero que te sea de utilidad.
NOTA: Ten en cuenta que en español la manera correcta de formatear un número decimal es 3.000,59 ya es otra cosa como exel los trate.

Comment: No es correcto tu respuesta puesto que `NUMBER(5, 2)` significa que el número máximo de digitos contanto la parte entera + la decimal es de 5, por tanto la parte entera sólo admite 3 dígitos y la decimal 2, y rango de valores admitidos iria desde **-999.99** hasta **999.99** @UHDante

Comment: Correcto, 100%, @DevCodeG gracias por el aporte, era un error que había pasado por alto. he editado la respuesta.